# Xamarin Forms: Switching between multiple navigation stacks is not smooth on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two navigation pages in `App.xaml.cs`

```
public static NavigationPage Stack1 {get; set;}
public static NavigationPage Stack2 {get; set;}
```

Initially `MainPage` is set to `Stack1` and somewhere in the app, I switch out stacks and set `MainPage` to `Stack2`. On iOS, this transition is not visible to the human eye, but on Android (API 23) I'm seeing a white flash while the stacks are being swapped.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: How do you switch NavigationPage?

Comment: That's probably some delay while setting up all the pages of the stack. The question is: why would you want to change the main page to another stack instead of using the existing stack und replacing its pages?

Comment: Using the existing stack has the same effect. I tried InsertPageBefore to put the new page as the first page and removed all other pages. This created the same flash. I tried removing all pages and then adding the new one, but this throws an error as the root page can't be removed if it's the page being displayed.

Comment: @Rohit `MainPage = Stack2;`

Comment: Usually this is not visible in real device, also swapping stack is not common, maybe u can try something with a loader to hide the flash.